# copy a specific filetype from multiple subfolders into one folder

Tags: batch-file, robocopy, copy, xxcopy

I want to copy from a folder with several subfolders all csv files to a single folder. But I only want files that are not older than 30 days.

This is what i have so far:

```
for /R C:\Source %%f in (*.csv) do copy %%f U:\Target
```

I know there are more possibilities with robocopy, but I can not use robocopy with my code:

```
for /R C:\Source %%f in (*.csv) do robocopy %%f U:\Target
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `forfiles` command, which has the option to specify a minimum date.

```
forfiles /p C:\Source /m *.csv /s /c "cmd /c copy @path U:\Target" /d 22-10-2019
```

Unfortunately there is no way to specify ‘files not older than [n] days’, that's why I used a hardcoded date.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you:

```
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ('forfiles /p SourcePath /m *.csv /s /c "cmd /c echo @path" /d -30') do copy "%%~a" TargetPath
```

Comment: Welcome on the site! Your script looks wonderful, but please explain what it does and how.